# Redirect Makefile output files into separate folder

Tags: makefile, directory, output

I have a 3rd Party SW where I'm not allowed to modify the Makefile. We got a package of sources with a folder 'Build/' where are placed all important files to run a build (several Makefiles, supporting scripts, linker files, ...). The problem is the Makefile is not designed very well so all the output files (obj, map file, err log, output folders, ...) are generated inside the Build/ folder. And not all are removed after 'clean'.

The output files are generated into the folder where the Makefile is placed.
**I'm just wondering if there is any chance to call a Makefile in a way the output is generated into a different folder.**

For example, I tried to call the Makefile from a different folder but without any help.

It just looks like this:

```
link_hex: compile $(LNK_FILE) $(PROJECT_NAME).hex
```

Instead of something like this:

```
link_hex: compile $(LNK_FILE) $(OUTPUT_PATH)/$(PROJECT_NAME).hex
```

The project contains many Makefiles so it is not so trivial to change only a few lines even if it would be allowed to change.

Comment: Those lines you are showing do not make sense in a Makefile. Please post real code in questions, not pseudocode. The way this question is asked would need an answer that does a grand tour of "how to build a Makefile".

Comment: You might want to check out [CMake](https://cmake.org/), which is pretty much the go-to build system for C/C++ today. It basically *generates* Makefiles (and Ninja build files, and MSVC solutions, and...) for you from a project definition file (CMakeLists.txt). It also supports out-of-source builds out of the box. Definitely easier than crafting and maintaining a non-trivial Makefile of your own.

Answer (score 3):

In similar situation in the past, I found it useful to create a "shadow" tree made of symlinks to the source tree, and then execute the build in the "shadow" tree. This will keep the source tree in "pristine" state, and place all output files into the new tree. Given symlinks need little space - space requirements are usually minimal

```
cp -rs /path/to/source shadow
cd shadow
make
```

Note that this will duplicate the folder structure - and place individual symlinks to each file.

As an alternative, you can use the 'cp -rl', creating hard links.

If you prefer symbolic links, and have the (deprecated) Imake package, there is a utility called 'lndir', which perform the same as above, and also support relative links. Sometimes resulting in more elegant solution.